# Understanding the > symbol

Tags: functions, inequality, elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm coming from a computer science background, there was recently an elementary math question I discussed with someone else that seemed to have me a bit stumped on the solution.

I have seen this question reposted here : [Given that exactly one of the 4 statements is correct, which one is it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4600862/given-that-exactly-one-of-the-4-statements-is-correct-which-one-is-it)

Which is also the following question:

> A multiple-choice test question offered the following four options relating to a certain statement:

A) The statement is true if and only if x > 1

B) The statement is true if x > 1

C) The statement is true if and only if x > 2

D) The statement is true if x > 2

> Given that exactly one of these options was correct, which one was it?

The solution has made me realize that there is something I fundamentally do not understand about inequalities, that hasn't caused me many problems up until now. Namely, this can be illustrated with my limited knowledge of set theory.

When I see a statement such as **if x > 1**
my natural assumption is that the consideration is $$x \in \{\mathbb{R} \; | \; x > 1\}$$
However from the solution it is evident that it is rather the consideration that
$$ x = \{\mathbb{R} \; | \; x > 1\}$$

Putting this another way, the consideration is that the condition applies to **x > 1** rather than to x which must be greater than 1. I however cannot see how this is evident from the question. This to me indicates that I perhaps do not understand how inequalities work.

What is the formal point in the definition for the symbol > that illustrates the problem in my understanding of this question?

Comment: I don't think the problem lies with the inequality; I think that in mathematical statements it is often assumed that there is a universal quantifier (a "for all") even when none is put there explicitly. To say something is true for $x>1$ is taken to mean it is true for all $x>1$, not just for some $x>1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given that exactly one of the 4 statements is correct, which one is it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4600862/given-that-exactly-one-of-the-4-statements-is-correct-which-one-is-it)

Comment: @mathlander The link doesn't answer my question

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, I was really not aware of that, this is was extremely confusing for me but in that case it fully makes sense.

Comment: It is only a puzzle about "if...,then..."

Comment: See here [the same post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605763/logic-question-doubt)

Comment: No special meaning of > is needed.

Comment: If we forget the original context, usually in math a formula with free variable x must be read as universally quantified.